# The rationale behind the mining reward of uncle block?

Tags: ghost-protocol

What is the rationale behind the mining reward of uncle block being 93.75% of a standard coinabase reward? And why was the percentage simplified and changed from the 87.5% in the original GHOST (https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Design-Rationale#uncle-incentivization).

Thanks.